# when use @MappedSuperclass,@Entity,@manytomany Could not determine type for: java.util.Set

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-orm, mappingexception

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdEntity /*extends AbstractPersistable<Integer>*/
        implements Serializable,Cloneable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.setId(id);
    }
}


    @Entity
@Table(name = "user")
//@AttributeOverride( name="id", column = @Column(name="id") )
public class User extends IdEntity{

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
//@AttributeOverride( name="id", column = @Column(name="id") )
public class Role extends IdEntity {

    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.rootls] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:286)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(roles)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1736)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `IdEntity` class you annotated your ID field (not getter), and in your sub classes `User` and `Role` you annotated your getters, which is not consistent. You must annotate either ONLY the fields, or ONLY the getters. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101448/column-or-basic-jpa-annotations-ignored-in-spring-data-jpa-schema-creation/20101538#20101538) question for a similar problem.

Alternatively, add `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` to your subclasses `Role` and `User`.

Comment: Excellent answer. It solved my exception here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have no attribute named `Set<Role> roles` in your `User` class. How were you able to compile this?